# how to find Xpath of grandchild(?) element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am new to Selenium and having difficulty figuring out how to write xpath.

I am able to find the element for the following xpath:

```
//*[@id="validation-item-0"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/ul/li[16]
```

How would I code in java to find the following xpath based on the above xpath?

```
//*[@id="validation-item-0"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/ul/li[16]/ul[1]/li/ul/li[4]
```

Being new to this, I am really confused on the ul and li items.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You should paste the relevant part of the xml code, together with your expected output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [XPath Syntax article](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

> `.` - Selects the current node

So you should be able to search the next element relative to the previous element, something like:

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='validation-item-0']/div[3]/div/div[2]/ul/li[16]"));
WebElement element2 = element1.findElement(By.xpath("./ul[1]/li/ul/li[4]"));
```

I would recommend getting rid of this `div[3]`, `li[16]`, etc. as even slight [markup](https://www.quora.com/What-is-markup-in-HTML) change will ruin your expression and test. Be aware that you can use [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)  like [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) so your expression would be more robust and reliable

Also this `ul[16]` doesn't look good, `<ul>` tag stands for the [Unordered List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) so you my expectation is that you should not be using index, but rather stick to the element text, something like:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(text(),'element text here')]"));
```

where [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) is the [XPath Function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) which could be used for partial match on the text

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T, that worked, appreciate your help.  I will look into your suggestions to make it more robust and reliable.  I am sure it will take me a while to get it to that point.  Thanks again.